# How to subscribe to a KDB tickerplant from an R-client?

Tags: r, kdb

I want to subscribe to a [KDB tickerplant](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Startingkdbplus/tick#6.3_Tickerplant) from an instance of [R](http://www.r-project.org/). Specifically, every time the tickerplant receives some new data, I want to run a handler on my R-client on the newly received data.

I have already read about

- Subscribing to a KDB tickerplant in [C](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-c-api-example#subscribing) and [Java](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-java-api#subscribing) - but these do not cover R
- Passing data between [R and KDB](http://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/with-r/) - but this does not cover subscribing to a tickerplant in R

So can anyone point me in the right direction or even better, have any examples?

Comment: you can maybe wrap th java call using `rjava`. It should not be very call the java code but maybe this will not the most efficient method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do it directly in R. You can call both Java and C from R though, so it would be just a case of writing a wrapper for those. There's some simple examples here (not kdb, but same principle): http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/rc/

I haven't looked recently but someone may well have contributed code on http://code.kx.com that does this.

The main thing is the listening loop - I'm not sure how that would work in R given you can't really start off a background thread.

The alternative is polling, which isn't a great alternative obviously.